# How to zoom a selected area on screen recording

Tags: screen-recording, camtasia

I am using camtasia studio for screen record. for small portion of my screen I want to zoom camera/recording area.
How can I zoom area when recording?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  We are here to help with programming questions, and unfortunately this doesn't see to be one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had the same need. I wanted to zoom in on an increasing counter in a callout window. I wanted the zoomed in "callout" to be perfectly synchronized with the actual video that was running.

I clipped the video I wanted zoomed in and put it in exactly the same location on an additional track above. Then, I copied the clip to a new project. Using the pan and zoom tools, I created a smaller video of just what I wanted by selecting the video size and positioning the pan window after setting my zoom.

It was easy to produce the video to a new WMV file and import that back into my original project. I used the copied clip as a guide of where to place the zoomed in video on the timeline. Finally, I removed the copied clip from the timeline because I no longer needed it.

For my needs, all I did was add a drop shadow to the zoomed callout and it was perfectly synchronized to my master video. A little fade in/fade out animation completed the polished effect.

Hope this helps.